# how to embed google map in my website.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a google map embeded in my website  and I have followed all the steps in the google website but I have not got to make the map to appear in the browser. Can anyone tell me what I is wrong in the code given below

**map.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Map Page</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>

<style type="text/css">
            #map {
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 253px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBLM6vAtHLu_SgqOtrAZvLSBoQUfILmPLI&sensor=false">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });


<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT lattitude, user_name,village_name, longitude FROM user u 
                      INNER JOIN village v
                       ON u.village = v.id")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['user_name'];
  $lat = $row['lattitude'];
  $lon = $row['longitude'];
  //$desc = $row['desc'];
//'<b>$name</b>
var_dump($query);

  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon <br />');\n");

}
echo "this is not working";
?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div id="page">
            <div id="wide-content">
              <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The map is comming if i take out your php part.. i.e. from your select statement.

Comment: but i tried the querry and it return the right resultsss

Comment: take out var_dump and echo "this is not working"; i think it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with what you write as debug information in your script. The printouts in the middle of the JS code are probably what are breaking your code.

Check with a JS console (like chrome's, or firebug) and you will find those errors there.

Try with this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['user_name'];
  $lat = $row['lattitude'];
  $lon = $row['longitude'];
  echo("addMarker('$lat',  '$lon');\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: @ Alex used the firebug it display: **<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>resource</b>(<i>5</i><font color='#2e3436'>,</font> <i>mysql result</i>)
</pre>addMarker(33.659049, 35.504174 <br />');
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>resource</b>(<i>5</i><font color='#2e3436'>,</font> <i>mysql result</i>)
</pre>addMarker(33.859246, 35.511971 <br />');
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>resource</b>(<i>5</i><font color='#2e3436'>,</font> <i>mysql result</i>)
</pre>addMarker(33.89996, 35.60476 <br />');
this is not working center = bounds.getCenter();
map.fitBounds(bounds);**

Comment: Yes, what you are seeing there is the result of the var_dump you made. That is generating something that javascript cannot understand. Can you try with the code I sent?